# MVC4 PartialViews without returning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Main view contains `@Ajax.ActionLink` links that updates a div target with partialViews. All works fine.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "MemberInfo", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divCurrentView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })

<div id="divCurrentView"></div>
```

Question is: When displaying a partialview and on click currently I update data and return to the same partial view that reloads the data. also reloads dropdownlists..etc `

Calling Partial View:

```
 public PartialViewResult MemberInfo(){
     .......
     ViewBag.Members= new SelectList(_db.Members, "Id", "Text");
     return PartialView("_MemberInfo",model);
 }


 [HttpPost]
 public PartialViewResult MemberInfo(InformationVM model){
      ....... update data
     //if I dont include the ViewBag again it will fail on reload
     ViewBag.Members= new SelectList(_db.Members, "Id", "Text");
     return PartialView("_MemberInfo",model);
 }
```

instead of return to the same PartialView can I just show a message on the screen "data was updated" within the partial view.?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question with more code. Right now its lots of guesswork.

Comment: Yes, you can. For example, return a 204 No Content Status code from your method. When your AJAX call succeeds, display the message. Or `return Content("Success!")` and display that.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster when I try return Content("Success!") I get an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult

Comment: Change the return type to `ActionResult`.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster It works it shows the message but it replaces the partial view. Is it possible to display the message with the partial view content?

Comment: So you want the _first_ click to load the partial and any subsequent click to load a message instead?

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster thats correct. Message within the partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your ActionLink, you can choose the element that gets replaced:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Do something", "_Methodname", new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "POST",
UpdateTargetId = "StatusMessage",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
}, new {@class = "text-danger"})
<span id="StatusMessage"></span>
```

This way, the message gets loaded into the span element.

---

In that case, I'd include the actionlink inside the div and replace the content of the div (including the actionlink) with the partial, this time including another (different) actionlink.

```
<div id="divCurrentView">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "MemberInfo", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divCurrentView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
</div>
```

Partial:

```
<div id="divCurrentView">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "MemberInfo", new AjaxOptions {
    HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "StatusMessage", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})
    <span id="StatusMessage"></span>
</div>
```

That way, the second (and subsequent) clicks will POST and use the different method in the controller.

Comment: I am using actionlink with replace element in the main view.. I update my question, can you please see it.